# I asked a question as an unregistered user earlier, but I can't reply to the answers now

Tags: discussion

This is the question I asked:
[How to generate Perlin Noise for materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222615/how-to-generate-perlin-noise-for-materials)

Now I can't reply because my PC doesn't know that it was really me who asked that question. What can I do?

Comment: I sent some points your way. That should let you reply. Try to delete this question once you have things working though, as it's more of a "how to use this site" question instead of a "how to use blender" question, so it'll probably get deleted anyway.

Comment: It says that I need 50 points to reply. :/ Thank you so much though! I can send you the points back if you want!

Comment: Don't worry. The points come from upvotes - they're yours to keep. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but just replied to me, did you not? You can "reply" to the others (answers) in the same manner (in the comment section)- just let everyone know you're the OP of the question.

Comment: I think I can reply here because I'm now using an account, and this is my question. But still thanks! I will make sure to get rid of this thread soon.

Comment: Yes, you can comment on your own questions anytime but you need 50 reputations to comment on other questions.

Comment: Oh, I remember that question, I answered it.

Answer (score 4):

You can request your account be merged by visiting https://blender.stackexchange.com/contact, while logged into your current account and selecting the "I want to merge user profile" option and then selecting "continue" on the pop up.

For the "other profile link" field, copy and paste in the URL to your other profile (the one that asked the question you linked).

This will open a support ticket, and if you can prove ownership of the account that asked the question via the ticket, your current account and that account will be merged, tying that account's content to your current account.

This will give you access to reply to content as the question's OP